# Simple Day / Date PHP not working?

Tags: php, date, html

I'm using the following to only show a div on a certain day and at a certain time and it's not working properly. It only seems to be recognising the time (and displays correctly when it should) but is ignoring the day altogether.

```
<?php
$current_time = date(G);
$current_day = date(l);
if ($current_day = "Thursday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 21) { ?>
<div id="content">content here</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

If I strip out the time reference altogether it still doesn't work. It just shows the div regardless of what day it is.

```
<?php
$current_day = date(l);
if ($current_day = "Thursday") { ?>
<div id="content">content here</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

I'm sure this is something super simple but I just can't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need quotes around `G` and `l` `date("G")` and `date("l")`

Comment: @RyanNaddy you dont NEED quotes...PHP automatically converts them to strings

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`. C. Malet has answered it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `=` instead of `==` in your IF statement.

It is an assign, which will always be true, except if you assign to `false`,`0`, `null` or empty string.

Comment: Thanks ;) Not sure if you can help with this but how could I get it to select every other Thursday instead of just every Thursday. I've found this snippet which kind of explains it but I'm not sure how to implement it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420401/php-select-every-other-wednesday

Comment: @Grant I believe you can get the week number, there are 52 weeks in a year so just check to see if the week in the year is even / odd (W)

Comment: Will that not change every year though? lol sorry maths is not my strong point.

Comment: @Grant if there were an odd number of weeks yes...but the fact that it is even makes it easier (might mess up only at the beginning of the year if the year changes between Monday to Thursday)..but idk think about it logically

Comment: so would something like this work `if (date('W')%2==1 && $current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 21)`?

Comment: Ahh I cracked it.. This works `<?php
$current_time = date(G);
$current_day = date(l);
$current_week = date(W);
if ($odd == $current_week%2 && $current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 21) { ?>
<div id="content">content</div> 
<?php } ?>` Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try == instead of =

```
if ($current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 21)
                  ^--------- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement has a syntax error.

```
if($current_day = "Thursday")
```

should be

```
if($current_day == "Thursday")
```

To do every other Thursday:

```
$week_number = date("W");
if($week_number % 2 <> 0 && $current_day == "Thursday") { echo "Do stuff"; }
```

Comment: Doh! How did I miss that! Code blind ;) Thanks very much, will tick this when it lets me. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Grant.  Saw your question above, but I don't have enough reputation to comment one someone else's answer.  I'll update my answer since I can't use carriage returns in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter of date has not placed with quotes.
try this, have worked here.

```
<?php
$current_time = date("G");
$current_day = date("l");
if ($current_day == "Friday" && $current_time >= 14 && $current_time <= 21) { ?>
<div id="content">content here</div> 
<?php } ?>
```