# I would like to put every other wednesday into an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, date

My Issue:

I have found a way to select every other Wednesday here: [PHP Select every other Wednesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420401/php-select-every-other-wednesday) with the following code.

```
<?php 

$number_of_dates = 10;

$start_date = new DateTime("1/1/20");
$interval   = DateInterval::createFromDateString("second wednesday");
$period     = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $number_of_dates - 1);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $datex = $date->format("m-d-Y").PHP_EOL;
    echo "$datex<br>";
}
?>
```

What I need to do is put every other Wednesday into an array.

I can put a range of dates into an array, but it uses every day in the range with the following code. I just need it to be every other Wednesday. How can I do this?

```
<?PHP
$dates = array();
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2020-01-01");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2020-1-31");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = (int) $interval->format('%R%a');
$currentTimestamp = $datetime1->getTimestamp();
$dates[] = date("m/d/Y", $currentTimestamp);
for ($x = 0; $x < $days; $x++)
{
   $currentTimestamp = strtotime("+1 day", $currentTimestamp);
    $dates[] = date("m/d/Y", $currentTimestamp);
}
print_r($dates);
?>
```

Comment: Just add the date into an array then inside the loop, instead of echo-ing it out?

Comment: `$dates = []; foreach ($period as $date) { $dates[] = $date->format("m-d-Y"); } var_dump($dates);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$dates = array();
$datetime = new DateTime();

for ($i = 0; $i < 52; $i++) {
    $datetime->modify('next Wednesday');
    array_push($dates, $datetime->format('m/d/Y'));
}

print_r($dates);
```

What does it do ?

1. it gets the current time (you can customize this in the new
   Datetime),
2. then loops for 52 times (you can customize this too in the for loop),
3. then finds the next wednesday using modify.

Live Demo : 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57c6a6b682a07f75bc1c507c588c844d84330610

Regards

Comment: Thank you. I added a start date and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet is already outputting the right set of dates, so you just would need to put each of those in an array, instead of echoing them.

(Although I don't know if it's really necessary to do so, since you can already loop over the `$period` variable - but it depends exactly what you plan to do with the data afterwards).

Example:

```
$number_of_dates = 10;

$start_date = new DateTime("1/1/20");
$interval   = DateInterval::createFromDateString("second wednesday");
$period     = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $number_of_dates - 1);

$dates = array(); //declare a new empty array
foreach ($period as $date) {
  $dates[] = $date; //add the date to the next empty array index
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Or if you actually want an array containing the string representations of those dates, in that specific format, then:

```
$dates2 = array();
foreach ($period as $date) {
   $dates2[] = $date->format("m-d-Y");
}

var_dump($dates2);
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e58e552edff204ae6df3ca9b437b8c597edf2b3

Comment: Thank you. Your example works great as well. The array will be put into a variable and used with a "if (in_array" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
<?PHP
$dates = [];
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2020-01-01");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2020-01-31");

$datetime1->modify('wednesday'); // Start with wednesday
while($datetime1 < $datetime2){
    $dates[] = $datetime1->format('Y-m-d');
    $datetime1->modify('second wednesday'); // Other Wednesday
}
print_r($dates);
?>
```